# How to install gcc/g++ 9 on CentOS 8 docker (centos:latest)

Tags: c++, docker, gcc, centos

In order to use the C++17 include `<filesystem>` I need gcc-9 package in my centos docker.

By default [centos:latest](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos) (aka 8) will install gcc 8.3.1 from the regular distro repo.

Is there any PPA, testing repo, whatever, where I can easily install a gcc-9 (or later) package (i.e. not build it from source)

Thanks !

note: need gcc-9 to have good C++17 `<filesystem>` support.
GCC 9 Release note:

> Using the types and functions in `<filesystem>` does not require linking with `-lstdc++fs` now.

src: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html

note2: CMake 3.16* doesn't support any cxx_filesystem compiler feature AFAIK.
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html

note3: you can found log here: https://github.com/Mizux/KalistoUnpacker/runs/642516660?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: Do you know the [devtoolset-9](https://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=27175)?

Comment: Thanks ! I think i used it long time ago but forget about it I'll give it a try !

Comment: @ThomasSablik Can't find a way to install it on Centos 8, contrary to Centos 7 which has scl and devtoolset packages.

Comment: https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-appstream-x86_64/gcc-toolset-9-gcc-9.1.1-2.4.el8.x86_64.rpm.html but don't know how ot use AppStream

Comment: What is the underlying problem you need to solve?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I just wanted to install g++ 9 since the default g++ (8.3.1) doesn't provide `<filesystem>` (ed without polluting my cmake with a linker flag)

Comment: How would you do it on a full Centos installation?

Answer (score 16):

Simply use `dnf`

```sh
dnf -y install gcc-toolset-9-gcc gcc-toolset-9-gcc-c++
source /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-9/enable
```

ref: https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-appstream-x86_64/gcc-toolset-9-gcc-9.1.1-2.4.el8.x86_64.rpm.html

Note: `source` won't work inside a Dockerfile so prefer to use:

```
ENV PATH=/opt/rh/gcc-toolset-9/root/usr/bin:$PATH
```

or better

```
RUN dnf -y install gcc-toolset-9-gcc gcc-toolset-9-gcc-c++

RUN echo "source /opt/rh/gcc-toolset-9/enable" >> /etc/bashrc
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c"]
RUN gcc --version
```

Answer (score 0):

this command work for me

```
dnf install gcc --best --allowerasing
```